# Как сделать так, чтобы netbeans увидел другой путь к TomCat?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

Изначально я установил 10 версию ***TomCat*** на *netbeans*, но она не работала. После этого я установил 9 версию, когда я запускал с помощью *RUN*, то в консоль выводилось сообщение:

```
Deploying on tomcat90:home=C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.0.18\apache-tomcat-10.0.18
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
```

Часть ***"C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.0.18\apache-tomcat-10.0.18"*** принадлежит старому пути, где ранее была установлена *10* версия. Не понимаю, как решить проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте в верхнем меню NetBeans **Tools->Servers** удалить 10-ю версию Tomcat и добавить 9-ю.
2. Затем, откройте свойства проекта (в дереве проекта нажать правой кнопкой мыши на самый верхний корневой элемент и выбрать **Properies**).
3. В пункте **Run** в поле **Server** укажите ваш установленный Tomcat.
4. Все. Скриншот прилагается.

[image: Выбор сервера]